# What does Illegal Instruction 4 mean with docker-compose on a Mac?

Tags: docker, docker-compose

Using OSX 10.11.1, first I installed the regular installer from Docker site and got this:

```
 → docker-compose --version 
Illegal Instruction: 4
```

Then I installed it through pip, the latest version, and got this.

```
    → docker-compose --version
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/docker-compose", line 9, in <module>
    load_entry_point('docker-compose==1.6.0dev', 'console_scripts', 'docker-compose')()
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/pkg_resources.py", line 357, in load_entry_point
    return get_distribution(dist).load_entry_point(group, name)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/pkg_resources.py", line 2394, in load_entry_point
    return ep.load()
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/pkg_resources.py", line 2108, in load
    entry = __import__(self.module_name, globals(),globals(), ['__name__'])
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/compose/cli/main.py", line 20, in <module>
    from ..progress_stream import StreamOutputError
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/compose/progress_stream.py", line 1, in <module>
    from compose import utils
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/compose/utils.py", line 11, in <module>
    from six.moves.queue import Empty
ImportError: No module named queue
```

How can I get a working version of Docker Compose installed on my Mac?

Answer (score 3):

The "Illegal Instruction: 4" is problem that happens sometimes with 10.11 (https://github.com/docker/compose/issues/271).

You can install a version of master from https://dl.bintray.com/docker-compose/master/ which doesn't have that issue, because it's built on a newer version of OSX.

To pip install, you should use a virtualenv (http://docs.docker.com/compose/install/#install-using-pip). The problem is that the version of `six` that OSX installs as a system package is very old, and is missing some things that are necessary for compose.

Comment: And where are the install instructions? What do I do with that file?

Comment: `chmod +x <filename>` and then you can run it the same way

Answer (score 2):

I finnaly got to install 1.6.0dev, build bacc2b7 on El Captain(10.11.02) by doing this as suggested by @dnephin.

```
curl -L https://dl.bintray.com/docker-compose/master/docker-compose-`uname -s`-`uname -m` > /usr/local/bin/docker-compose && chmod +x /usr/local/bin/docker-compose
```

but then I got an API version mismatch error

```
ERROR: client is newer than server (client API version: 1.22, server API version: 1.21)
```

so I had to create a new boot2docker VM runnning docker 1.10.

```
docker-machine create -d virtualbox --virtualbox-boot2docker-url=http://sirile.github.io/files/boot2docker-1.10.iso dev
```

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE:** This issue appears to have been solved in docker-compose 1.7.0-rc1.
See: https://github.com/docker/compose/issues/271#issuecomment-201203732

Once 1.7.0 is officially released you should be okay.

In the meantime, if you need a working 1.6.* binary for any reason, you can download one here, that has been compiled to work directly on older macs that had this issue: 
https://github.com/WidgetsBurritos/docker-compose-old-mac